# How to change uvicorn loggings?

Tags: python, discord, fastapi, uvicorn, python-logging

I'm making a discord api wrapper on top of FastAPI and i wanna change the uvicorn logs.

I want to change the uvicorn logs style, i have tried some libs like, rich, loguru, but they are working completely at different, and uvicorn's logs works different

Comment: To customize uvicorn's logs, you need to customize/redirect its logger instance. I've used [this example](https://gist.github.com/nkhitrov/a3e31cfcc1b19cba8e1b626276148c49) in the past to redirect uvicorn's logs through loguru.